# Cannot find module 'heroku-run'

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Tried to run `heroku logs` to check an error, got this:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
 !   Error in heroku-run:
 !   Cannot find module 'heroku-run'
 !   See ~/.heroku/error.log for more info.
```

Now every time I run a heroku command I get that message. Tried updating heroku, no change. Tried installing heroku-run, not a gem. Checked the error log and it just says the same thing:

```
2016/04/09 22:51:45 Error: Cannot find module 'heroku-run'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/heroku-script-021789235:34:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as you since a couple of minutes ago, hopefully it is a transient issue

Comment: Yeah, I'm also getting the error. This happened right after I pushed something to master and it failed, now I can't even get log messages'

Comment: Glad it's not just me. As a brand-new heroku user (as of two hours ago) this sort of thing is not encouraging - I thought it was something I'd done. (If it *was* something I did, and I broke heroku.. sorry everybody!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there was an issue with the heroku-toolbelt client for osx, run `heroku update` to get a fixed version.

Comment: $ heroku update
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'heroku-apps'


This is on ubuntu.

Comment: Tried an update, removed and reinstalled also. Have it installed through apt, maybe I'll try building it. I'm running Ubuntu also

Comment: Somehow I hadn't tried `heroku update`. After I ran that I was prompted to install again through apt, even though it was all up to date. After that it mysteriously started working. Thanks.

Comment: Still not functional here even after a complete re-install. If this is what heroku has to offer it's not terribly encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu I had to:

```
sudo aptitude purge heroku heroku-toolbelt
rm -rf ~/.heroku
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

before things started worked again.